# why i only get one character at one time when i use read()?

Tags: c, linux

I connect the Tx and Rx of TTY directly,and i write a string to the TTY, then,i use read() expect to get the same string i wrote before. When i run the program, i find that i could write the whole string to the TTY one time, but i only could read one character at each time when i use read() later.Please help me figure out why this happen,and how can i solve this.
The system i use is Ubuntu14.04, and the compiler is gcc 4.8.2.Thank you !

This is the main function i wrote:

```
int main(){
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR);
if(fd == -1)
{
    perror("serialport error\n");
}
else
{
    printf("open ");
    printf("%s",ttyname(fd));
    printf(" succesfully\n");
}

set_speed(fd,115200);
if (set_Parity(fd,8,1,'N') == FALSE)  {
    printf("Set Parity Error\n");
    exit (0);
}
char buf[100] = "aaaaaaaaaa";
char buf_r[100]= "12314";
int wl= write(fd,buf,strlen(buf)+1);
printf("write succesfully length %d\n",wl);
int rl=read(fd,buf_r,100);
printf("read succesfully length %d\n",rl);
while (rl<wl){
  rl+=read(fd,buf_r+rl,100);
  printf("read succesfully length %d\n",rl);
}
printf("buf_r=%s\n",buf_r);
close(fd);
return 0;}
```

This is the result of program:

```
open /dev/ttyUSB0 succesfully

write succesfully length 11

read succesfully length 1

read succesfully length 2

read succesfully length 3

read succesfully length 4

read succesfully length 5

read succesfully length 6

read succesfully length 7

read succesfully length 8

read succesfully length 9

read succesfully length 10

read succesfully length 11

buf_r=aaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Because you're reading faster than you're writing.

Comment: The write() return but data didn't send to the actual device , the data is send to the linux kernel buffer, then the character is send to the device one by one.So ,when i use read() later, i only get one character at a time, is that right?

Comment: No, the data is written to the hardware. But how fast is the hardware writing?

Comment: Actually, i connect the Rx and the Tx of TTY by using jumper cap, So, i think when the data is written to the device , it should be read by my computer immediately.

Comment: You believe that all the data should be sent over the line immediately? But then what does the "115200" in the program mean?

Comment: You are right , i did not thought that before, thank you ！

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Hmmmm... that's not right.  Terminal driver in cooked mode (normal mode) doesn't allow a process to get the chars until a `\r` is input.  And your program will get blocked in `read(2)` until all characters are sent.  Have you configured your terminal in raw mode before doing such a test?  Are you using some kind of unix or windows operating system?

Comment: @LuisColorado: `read()` will *attempt* to read that many bytes, but it is not required to block until the desired amount has been read, only that at least 1 byte has been read (giving a non-zero return value).

Comment: Sorry but I have to disagree, read `termios(3)` and the tty modes and you'll get there the use of raw mode and cooked mode.  This is implemented from the ancient times of unix (before it got seen by the world).  One tty in cooked mode (normal mode) doesn't pass the character buffer to the process until it has seen an *end of line* terminator.  The terminal will not allow the process to see any of those characters before the `\r` terminator has been read.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: computers are fast, serial ports are slow.

With the settings that you are using (8 none 1) each character takes 10 bit times to transmit (1 start bit, 8 data bits, 0 parity bits, 1 stop bit). Since the baud rate is 115200, the character transmission rate is 11520 characters per second. So each character takes 87 microseconds. Sending 11 characters takes 957 microseconds, or about 1 millisecond.

Calling `read` on a modern processor (with data waiting) takes only a few microseconds. So the code can read data much faster than the serial port transfers the data.

As a simple test, call `usleep(1000)` before the `read` and you should get all of the data in one `read`.

Comment: Thank you to point that for me, actually, i have to call usleep(20000) before call read(), then i can read the whole data at a time.

Comment: @xiongfeng This is not guaranteed. You can never be sure that `read` returns all the data that's available. Always call `read` in a loop.

Comment: I fear not.  Unix tty driver will make process wait for all chars to be transmitted before allowing a process to get them.  And that in case you finish your written string with a `\r` char.  Read `termios(2)` to get information about the actual reasons of this.

Comment: @LuisColorado I see your point about raw mode versus cooked mode. Evidently the OP has the tty in raw mode, since the process is clearly *not* waiting for all of the characters.

Comment: even in that case, VMIN and VTIME play an important role in the number of chars actually received.  In ancient unix, once a tty was closed, it assumed a default cooked configuration, but linux is not unix...